# Icecast2 Mountpoint Not Displaying

Tags: raspberry-pi, icecast

I am adding Icecast2 to my Raspberry PI and can not get the mountpoint to show in the admin.

[image]

Here is my darkice.cfg

```html
[general]
duration        = 0      # duration in s, 0 forever
bufferSecs      = 1      # buffer, in seconds
reconnect       = yes    # reconnect if disconnected

[input]
device          = dmic_sv # Soundcard device for the audio input
sampleRate      = 44100   # sample rate 11025, 22050 or 44100
bitsPerSample   = 16      # bits
channel         = 2       # 2 = stereo

[icecast2-0]
bitrateMode     = cbr       # constant bit rate ('cbr' constant, 'abr' average)
#quality         = 1.0       # 1.0 is best quality (use only with vbr)
format          = mp3       # format. Choose 'vorbis' for OGG Vorbis
bitrate         = 320       # bitrate
server          = localhost # or IP
port            = 8000      # port for IceCast2 access
password        = raspberry    # source password for the IceCast2 server
mountPoint      = turntable.mp3  # mount point on the IceCast2 server .mp3 or .ogg
name            = Turntable
highpass        = 18
lowpass         = 20000
description = Turntable
```

Help!

Comment: Please look at the log output of both `darkice` and `icecast2`. Those usually contain valuable information.

Comment: @TBR https://codeshare.io/aV7Ml8

Comment: Check Icecast connection password, it should be "raspberry" (at least darkice/icecast have to have the same password)